# What are the disadvantages of using ng-style?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-style, angularjs-ng-style

I have used `ng-style` in code, but my manager said not to use `ng-style` since it will create problem.

I still don't know what problem he faced before and I would like to know what are the disadvantages of using `ng-style`?

Comment: ng- prefix is just invalid attribute for HTML markup

Comment: inline styling should not be used unless if it is not that much complicated UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You cannot reuse the styles anywhere else.
2. The html markup of the page becomes cumbersome, and tough to parse for the naked eye.
3. Since, they are not stored at a single place, they are tough to be edited
4. This approach does not provide consistency across your application. The inline styles on elements can cause a major headache.
5. It does not provide you with the browser cache advantage. The files are repeatedly downloaded by the client on every request. Instead, consider using External style sheets.
6. Inline styles take precedence over page-level style declarations and external style sheets. So you could accidentally override styles that you did not intend.
7. It's impossible to style pseudo-elements and -classes with inline styles. For example, with external and internal style sheets, you can style the visited, hover, active, and link color of an anchor tag.

Please refer

[Inline style disadvantages](https://vineetgupta22.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/inline-vs-internal-vs-external-css/)

[Other link](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-css-inline-style-3466446)